# Best colours for web app

Tags: css, colors

I am making a PHP web app but it looks kind of plain right now,

Does anyone know of any good color picking websites or recommend any colors (preferably shades of blue) that I can use in my CSS?

Thanks.
RayQuang

Comment: This belongs on www.doctype.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend:

http://www.colourlovers.com/

for all your color needs.

*Note: I'm in no way affiliated with the website. I just like it.*

Comment: Thanks, this one seems perfect to me, also it doesn't use flash which is great!

Comment: I came across this answer quite some time ago, but I couldn't find it any more. I'm so happy to have found it again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try http://kuler.adobe.com/ and choose among hundreds of great color themes or compose your own.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.colourlovers.com/

is a great place for patterns and color schemes

p.s. you can also find great icons at: http://www.iconfinder.com/browse

P.s.s lol we recommended the same site :P

Answer (score 0):

I like this: http://color.aurlien.net/. It's just a color picker, though.